# Am Yisroel Chai - Source?

Tags: minhag

Besides for [this story](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31168/rav-yonason-eibeschitzs-puzzle) of Rabbi Yonasan Aibshitz, is there any other source for the phrase "Am Yisroel Chai"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am_Yisrael_Chai#History

Comment: @shmosel Any references to this phrase between the time of Rabbi Yonasan Aibishtz and the Holocaust?

Comment: Duplicate? [Is there any Torah source for the phrase "עם ישראל חי"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92467/is-there-any-torah-source-for-the-phrase-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%a8%d7%90%d7%9c-%d7%97%d7%99)